# Is it possible to emulate bluetooth connection between two devices in Android Studio or using some other emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-bluetooth, google-nearby

I'm writing an app that uses Google's Nearby Connections to connect two android devices via bluetooth and exchange data. But it appears the native emulator in Android Studio does not support bluetooth. Is there some other emulator I could use for testing purposes, or is using two physical devices my only option?

Comment: Installing Android in VirtualBox may help here. You can find details from http://niro-offonatangent.blogspot.com/2011/06/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator.html

Comment: @Akki Thanks, but not having much luck with that. Tried with Virtualbox and VMWare Player, different bluetooth dongles, different android images. The result is always the same. I can see the bluetooth device checked in the VM's usb device list. However, trying to enable bluetooth has no effect - looks like it's just keeps trying to turn it on indefinitely but never succeeding.